# Default order with Spring Boot sorting and paging

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring Boot 3.2.2 application with paging and sorting. It works perfectly with one exception: The initial data is gathered unordered from the database. I would the initial data to be presorted descending by Id.

Currently, it's using the Spring Boot `findAll(pageable)` methodology. Does anyone know how can I make this work?

This is from my service test code:

```java
public Page<Person> getPage(int pageNo, int pageSize, String sortField, String sortDirection) {
    Sort sortOption = sortDirection.equalsIgnoreCase(Sort.Direction.ASC.name()) ? 
        Sort.by(sortField).ascending() : Sort.by(sortField).descending();
    Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(pageNo - 1, pageSize, sortOption);
    return this.personRepository.findAll(pageable);
  }
```

I can add this the repository:

```java
Page<Person> findAllByOrderByIdDesc(Pageable pageable).
```

But when I try replacing `findAll` with this, the paging works, but the sorting does not.

Comment: Spring Boot 4.0.0? Are you sure? AFAIK, the latest version is 3.2.2. :)

Comment: My mistake, its 3.2.2

Comment: Have you looked into `@PageableDefault` and `@SortDefault` and the related concepts?

Comment: Yes, I've tried both of these concepts with no luck

Comment: you can check [this example](https://github.com/bezkoder/spring-boot-jpa-paging-sorting/blob/master/src/main/java/com/bezkoder/spring/data/jpa/pagingsorting/controller/TutorialController.java#L80) it show how to use Pageable.